# regular expression to find variables in a string

Tags: java, regex, java-stream

There is a string that could have one or more "variables" in it.  A variable is defined by {[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]*}.  Looking for a way to escape the curly bracket, but in the end I am looking to this:

```
Map<String, String> variableMap = getVarilableMap();
wrapperTDO.getValueList()
    .stream()
    .forEach(a -> /* if a.getValue() has one or more variables, replace from the map variableMap, and update setValue() */ );
```

The questions are:

1. what is the correct regex to find all the variables in the string and not to find false positives, like {abc is nothing, or {ab{ac} should only be {ac}.
2. Is there some way to put this all into one lamda in java to minimize if statements?
3. Is this a two step process, filter down to those with variables and then to a replace on only those?

Comment: What does TDO stand for?

Comment: Cant you just escape it with \\{ ??

Comment: [Give me a regex that do X questions should be closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed/).

Comment: can you show us some examples please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **don't want** curly brackets to be a part of the match, use a regex pattern

```
(?<=\\{)[\\w+-]+(?=\\})
```

If you **do want** the curly brackets to be a part of the match, use regex pattern

```
\\{[\\w+-]+\\}
```

Comment: Yep, that generally worked, but... it turns out I cannot use brackets, I have to use #, so rather than radically changing this question, I am going to ask a new question.  Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50517205/regex-to-find-variables-surrounded-by-in-a-string

Answer (score 1):

Simply excape it with `\`

```
\{[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]*}
```

obviously you need to escape `\` as well so you will end up with

```
\\{[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]*}
```

Here is an example https://www.regextester.com/?fam=103576

Comment: I assume `{}` is not wanted to be matched, so you should use `+` instead of `*` to ensure at least one character is matched.

Answer (score 0):

Escape { using {.

To create a capturing group, surround it with ().

Look at the Pattern and Matcher classes. The Matcher will help you find all the groups.